Use list comprehension with if, else, and for-loop while only keeping list items that meet a condition
I use list comprehension to load only the images from a folder that meet a certain condition.
In the same operation, I would also like to keep track of those that do not meet the condition. This is where I am having trouble.
If the if and else conditions are at the beginning, each iteration yields a resulting element. The items that are caught by else are replaced by None rather than being excluded from the result list.
I can't figure out how to add an else condition such that an operation can be done on the items caught by else without including them in the resulting list.
here is a simplified and generalized version of the code:
exclude_imgs = [1, 3]
final = [
    n
    for ix, n in enumerate(sorted(["img1", "img4", "img3", "img5", "img2"]))
    if ix + 1 not in exclude_imgs
]

[ins] In [4]: final
Out[4]: ['img2', 'img4', 'img5']

adding else condition to store excluded images:
exclude_imgs = [1, 3]
excluded = []
final = [
    n if ix + 1 not in exclude_imgs else excluded.append(n)
    for ix, n in enumerate(sorted(["img1", "img4", "img3", "img5", "img2"]))
]

[ins] In [6]: final
Out[6]: [None, 'img2', None, 'img4', 'img5']

[ins] In [7]: excluded
Out[7]: ['img1', 'img3']

How can I write this so that the results are as follows:
final: ['img2', 'img4', 'img5']
excluded: ['img1', 'img3']

?

It's sometimes clearer to write a normal loop rather than a list comprehension. Here, it would also prevent the not-so-good use of the comprehension for its side effects (the appending to excluded) and the need to filter final at the end...

See the partition recipe in the itertools documentation.

You still have the excluded once, why twice?

@ThierryLathuille Agreed that there are clearer solutions here. I didn't mean to focus so much on the adding to another list, but rather on how to access the else items without requiring a value for them in the result list.

Consider not using a list comprehension at all, precisely because you want to create two lists, not just one.
exclude_imgs = [1, 3]
excluded = []
final = []

for ix, n in enumerate(sorted(["img1", "img4", "img3", "img5", "img2"]), start=1):
    (excluded if ix in excluded_imgs else final).append(n)


This is a great solution for creating two lists. I perhaps chose a bad example but my goal was rather to see how far we can take list comprehension using if/else where the else items are accessible (for any use, not just adding to another list) without being required in the resulting list.

Not recommended, but we can use the falsey value of excluded.append as an additional condition:
exclude_imgs = [1, 3]
excluded = []
final = [
    n 
    for ix, n in enumerate(sorted(["img1", "img4", "img3", "img5", "img2"]))
    if  ix+1 not in exclude_imgs or excluded.append(n)
]

Logic is as follows:

If ix+1 is not in exclude_imgs, then it adds it to the list without checking the second condition and avoids adding the element to excluded.
If ix+1 is in exclude_imgs, then the first condition evaluates to false which then looks at the second condition, executing the excluded.append(n). excluded.append(n) always returns None so it evaluates to False, preventing it being added to final, but still appending to excluded.

